# How to retrieve request scope value in jsp with struts1 tags?

Tags: jsp, scriptlet, struts1

Below is how I am setting my value to request scope. And not able to retrieve in  java script alert, need some one help.

```
`request. set Attribute ("token", token);`
```

I am using like this
    `<bean:parameter name="token"/>`

But no luck..!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following code in head tag.

This code takes the token value from the request and sets it to a local variable.

```
<%
   String token = request.getAttribute("token").toString();                     
%>
```

This code takes the value from the local variable and sets it to a javascript variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    var tokenValue =  "<%=token%>";
    alert(tokenValue);  
</script>
```

Comment: Also I tried reading directly from request scope as below, alert("${requestScope.token}") & working perfect.

Comment: That's great to hear. Select it as the accepted answer so that if anyone else has the same issue it will help them.